# Swift Ui - Different View(Layout) for first item of a List

Tags: list, swiftui

I am relatively new to `Swift`. I want to accomplish that the first item of the `weatherList` is displayed with a different View.

Unfortunately I get this error in those 2 Lines `(VStack and at ForEach-Line)`. If i put away the `if i == 0` then and just use for normal layout for all `listitems` there is no error.

```
ERROR: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

Here is my code:

```
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {

        VStack { // here first error

            if self.model.error != nil {

                Text(self.model.error!)

            }

            ForEach(0..<self.model.weatherList.count, id: \.self) { i in // here second error



                if i == 0 {

                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])) {

                        RowView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])

                    }

                }

                else{

                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])) {

                        RowView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])

                    }

                }

            }



        }

        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Weather in " + UserSettings.instance.locationSetting))

        .navigationBarItems(trailing:

            Button(action: {

                self.model.reload()

            }) {

                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")

            }

            .disabled(model.reloading)

        )

    }

}
```

Would appreciate each advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tries this, but what if you wrap the NavigationLink like this:

```
    if i == 0 {
        AnyView(
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])) {
                RowView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])
        })
    } else {
        AnyView(
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])) {
                RowView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to know for sure without having the rest of your code to make this compile, but I mocked it up locally and it looks like all you need to change is:

```
            ForEach(0..<self.model.weatherList.count, id: \.self) { i in
```

to

```
            ForEach(0..<self.model.weatherList.count) { i in // remove the id: argument
```

## Explanation:

If you're using a range to iterate through your array, you don't use the id: argument. The range is automatically identifiable. The `ForEach(_:id:content:)` initialiser is used for cases where you might say

```
ForEach(self.model.weatherlist, id: \.self) { model in 
    SomeView(model: model)
}
```

Does that compile for you?

Edit: The example you've given looks like it will do the same thing whether the index is 0 or not. Is there a reason why it doesn't work if you try:

```
                ForEach(0..<self.model.weatherList.count) { i in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])) {
                    RowView(model: self.model.weatherList[i])
                }
            }
```